# Laravel - share and update variable across controller functions

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to share and update a variable (`$shipval`) in my controller functions in a Laravel project.

**Controller**:

```
<?php

class PaymentController extends BaseController {

  var $shipval='0';

  function postCheckout() {
    // ship_cost gets its value from a select element
    $ship_cost= Input::get('shipping');

    // below its supposed to update the global var $ship_cost value accordingly
    if ($ship_cost == 0) {
      $shipval = '0';
    }

    if ($ship_cost == 1) {
      $shipval = '4.99';
    }

    if ($ship_cost == 2) {
      $shipval = '8.99';
    }
  }

  function postPayment() {
    dd($this->shipval); //At the moment outputs 0
  }
}
```

The output of the `dd($this->shipval);` should get updated in the `postCheckout()` function. Instead is just printing the initial value set above `(0)`. I also, I tried to have `$this->shipval == '4.99'` inside the `if` statements, but still is not updating the value. Is it possible to do so in Laravel 4?

Comment: You need to show the full controller code class. And when this functions are called? Which route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use $this->shipval instead of $shipval. So it would be like this for example:

```
$this->shipval = '4.99';
```

Comment: beat me to it. OP is using it correctly in one method, just not the other

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. In the first function this works perfectly. When it comes to the second function the output of `dd($this->shipval)` still remains the same as the initial one which is zero. Instead it should change accordingly `(0, 4.99, 8.99)`.

Comment: Which one do you call first?

Comment: I see now, it's a controller. You should use a variable in this case. Store this information in session or database.

Comment: I already thought of  storing it in session, but I was after a way to update the global variable `$shipval` from inside the `postCheckout()` function and grab the updated result inside the `postPayment()`.

Comment: It would work if both methods would be called in runtime, though since it's 2 separate HTTP requests, that won't work.

Comment: I see. I would either change the structure of my methods or store the `var` somewhere.